# Calling function defined in library from dart webcomponent

Tags: dart, web-component

The web application has following code in app.dart

```
library app;
import 'dart:html';
var _loginClass; 

void main() {
 _loginClass = 'hide_login'; //set style to hide login web component by setting display:none

}
void showLogin(e) {
  _loginClass = 'show_login';
 print("span clicked");
}
void hideLogin(e) {
_loginClass = 'hide_login';
}
```

calling hideLogin(e) function from App.dart hides the web component. but calling it from web component does not work.

css is defined as follows:

```
.hide_login {
display: none;
}

.show_login {
 display = block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please also show the HTML that has the data bindings and event handler declarations? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that you have "display: none;" and "display = block;". The second is not valid syntax.

If that's not the right answer, try adding:

```
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';
```

And then call dispatch(); after setting _loginClass.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be more dartish to use

```
<template instantiate="bool expression">
```

This makes showing and hiding a custom element like a login component incredibly easy

example:

login.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-login" constructor="LoginComponent" extends="div">
      <template instantiate="if showLogin">
        ...
        <button on-click="validateLogin()">Login</button>
      </template>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

LoginComponent.dart

```
import "package:web_ui/web_ui.dart";

class LoginComponent extends WebComponent {
  bool showLogin = true;

  bool validateLogin() {
    ...
    showLogin = false;
  }
}
```

Check out http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/ for further details